# Adding time to stopwatch

Tags: .net, vb.net

and good day! I have two questions:

I have a stopwatch that I am using to display elapsed time:

```
Dim swTimer As New Stopwatch
Private WithEvents StartingTimer As New Timer

Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    swTimer.Start()
    StartingTimer.Interval = 1000
    StartingTimer.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub StartingTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles StartingTimer.Tick
    btnStart.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", swTimer.Elapsed.Hours, swTimer.Elapsed.Minutes, swTimer.Elapsed.Seconds)
End Sub
```

**Question 1**: How do I change the button to display just the minutes and seconds? For example, 1 hour, 20 minutes, and 44 seconds would read: 104:44.

I also have 2 addition buttons:
 1. btnStartSubtract
 2. btnStartAdd

**Question 2**: When I press btnStartSubtract, how do I add subtract quarter of a second from the timer so that I can go "back" in time? Same thing with btnStartAdd?

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's no such format. You have to make a conversion manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain a separate TimeSpan variable with an offset to be applied when displaying the elapsed time.

A TimeSpan has a [TotalMinutes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalminutes?view=netframework-4.7.2) property which you can use to get... the total minutes. It includes a fractional part, but we can truncate that.

A little bit of extra work is needed in case the TimeSpan is negative...

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim swTimer As New Stopwatch
    Private WithEvents startingTimer As New Timer
    Dim swOffset As New TimeSpan

    Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
        swTimer.Start()
        startingTimer.Interval = 200
        startingTimer.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub StartingTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim elap = swTimer.Elapsed + swOffset
        Dim mins = Math.Abs(Math.Truncate(elap.TotalMinutes))
        Dim secs = Math.Abs(elap.Seconds)
        Dim sgn = If(elap < TimeSpan.Zero, "-", "")

        btnStart.Text = String.Format("{0}{1}:{2:00}", sgn, mins, secs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnStartSubtract_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStartSubtract.Click
        swOffset = swOffset.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250))

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnStartAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStartAdd.Click
        swOffset = swOffset.Add(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250))

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddHandler startingTimer.Tick, AddressOf StartingTimer_Tick

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        RemoveHandler startingTimer.Tick, AddressOf StartingTimer_Tick

    End Sub

End Class
```

There is a bug in that code in that if you get it counting up from a negative value, it counts -0:01 -0:00 0:00 0:01... - I'm sure you will enjoy fixing that :)

Comment: Hey, thanks so much! I'm going to try this out! Just one quick question - may I ask why you set the startingTimer.Interval = 200 instead of 1000?

Comment: @JasonMills It makes the display updates smoother, and gives faster feedback when btnStartSubtract or btnStartAdd is clicked.

Comment: Ohhhh, thank you! Sorry for the stupid followup question but...is there any way to get the minute counter to display in triple digits? So 1 second in would be 000:01?

Comment: @JasonMills Just use `{1:000}` in the String.Format, in the same way as you use `{2:00}`.